# How to run a shell script on all amazon ec2 instances that are part of a autoscaling group?

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

Can anyone please tell me how to run a shell script on all the ec2 instances that are part of an auto scaling group?

The scenario is that I have a script that I want to run on many ec2 instances that are turned on automatically as part of auto scaling group. The native approach is to SSH to each instance and run the script. I am looking for a way by which it can run automatically on all the instances when I run it on one of the ec2 instance or any better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: best to ask on serverfault.com

Comment: I posted there also to find the ans quickly at: http://serverfault.com/questions/685243/how-to-run-a-shell-script-on-all-amazon-ec2-instances-that-are-part-of-a-autosca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement in many different ways...

1. Use awscli to get all instances in auto scaling group
   aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-name myTestGroup
2. [SSHkit](https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit) is interesting tool run commands on remote servers

or

Invest your time to automate your infrastructure in proper tools like puppet, chef. With puppet mcollective you can do magic, including what you have asked about.

Update:

When you add instance to autoscaling group new tag name=aws:autoscaling:groupName, value=name_of_assigned_autoscaling_group is added, thus its easy to find it searching for this tag.

`$ asgName=testASG`

`$ aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=tag-key,Values='aws:autoscaling:groupName' Name=tag-value,Values=$asgName  --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,PublicIpAddress]'`

The output you will get from the command above is the instance name and public IP:

`i-4c42aabc 52.1.x.y`

You can use this is your script...

Comment: I need a shell script to determine all the IP of the instances of auto scaling group

Comment: When you add instance to autoscaling group new tag name=aws:autoscaling:groupName, value=name_of_assigned_autoscaling_group is added, thus its easy to find it searching for this tag. I updated my answer

Comment: This error occured when i try to run this script. Error parsing parameter '--filters': should be: Key value pairs, where values are separated by commas, and multiple pairs are separated by spaces.
--filters Name=string1,Values=string1,string2 Name=string1,Values=string1,string2

Comment: What version (command to check "aws --version") of awscli do you use? I doubled checked and it works, my version is "aws-cli/1.7.18 Python/2.7.6 Darwin/14.3.0"

Comment: Please also show the commands you use, it looks like you do a typo.

Comment: I use the latest version of awscli and i use exactly the same code you give with my asg group name

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to add that shell script to the userdata in a NEW Launch Config and then update the autoscaling group.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts

Updating the Launch Config

> if you want to change the launch configuration for your Auto Scaling group, you must create a launch configuration and then update your Auto Scaling group with the new launch configuration. When you change the launch configuration for your Auto Scaling group, any new instances are launched using the new configuration parameters, but existing instances are not affected.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/LaunchConfiguration.html

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using Chef. Opsworks (an aws product) is chef plus a lot of things that will do exactly what you want and give you even more flexibility.

Comment: This is no longer viable as Opsworks is end of life.

Answer (score 0):

[Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/send-command.html) perhaps?

You can use it to invoke scripts as well:
**Nice cheat: Select Run Command on the left-side menu of the EC2 section. Click the "Run Command" button. Then setup your AWS-RunShellScript. Type in your code. Then at the bottom there is a dropdown labelled: "AWS Command Line Interface command", select the correct platform and copy/paste the command into a script.*

```
$Command_Id = aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunPowerShellScript" --targets '{\"Key\":\"tag:Name\",\"Values\":[\"RunningTests\"]}' --parameters '{\"commands\":[\"Start-Process \\\"C:\\\\path\\\\to\\\\scripts\\\\LOCAL_RUN.ps1\\\"\"]}' --comment "Run Tests Locally" --timeout-seconds 3800 --region us-east-1 --query 'Command.CommandId' --output text | Out-String
```

**Per the question:** Use your Auto Scaling Group Name instead of "RunningTests." Or, in the console: In your "Run Command" setup. Select the "Specifiying a Tag" radio button, then "Name" and your Auto Scaling Group.
[image: Select Auto Scaling Group in Run Command]

***Note:** The command above is windows powershell, but you can convert your script to Linux/OS or whatever by selecting the correct platform when in the Run Command setup.

****Note:** Ensure your User on that instance has the AmazonSSMFullAccess permission setup to run the commands.

*****Note:**The SSM Agent comes installed on Windows Instances by default. If you are running Linux or something else, you might need to [install the SSM Agent.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-agent.html)

Answer (score 0):

For a simplistic implementation you can use python fabric (http://www.fabfile.org/). It is a tool to run commands from a local or bashin instance to list of servers.

Here is a repo which has basic scaffolding and examples. Lot of CICD tools are having features to target this requirements, but I found fabric the easiest to implement fo simple setup.

https://github.com/techsemicolon/python-fabric-ec2-aws